# How to resolve the missing python gsm module while executing airprobe

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

For quite some while I've been trying to work with usrp, gnuradio and airprobe. I've successfully received a data dump using usrp but when I try to use gsm_receive100.py on the captured cfile, I am always getting this error:

```
./gsm_receive100.py cfile 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gsm_receive100.py", line 12, in <module>
    import gsm
ImportError: No module named gsm
```

I tried to look every possible place for the particular python module that is missing, both in the web and within the distribution itself but without any success so far. Has anyone faced a similar problem before, and do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Supratim -

This is either a problem with your install of the out-of-tree module, or with the module itself. To debug this, you (and anyone helping you) really needs a lot more information:

For starters:
1) What happens when you try to import the module in the Python shell?
2) What turns up when you use slocate to find the module on your computer?
3) What does $ env $PYTHONPATH tell you?

Also, this really isn't a good question for Stack Overflow. This would be better asked on the GNURadio mailing list, which is very active.

For support, you should really look to the mailing lists:

For GNU Radio: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/discuss-gnuradio

For things specific to USRPs: http://lists.ettus.com/mailman/listinfo/usrp-users_lists.ettus.com

In general, the community uses the lists almost exclusively for support.